# Hibernate JPA - entities is are not detected on wildfly startup

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

im working on a project in Java. Idea is with a react fron-end i would feed the database using java as back end. So far i prepared the back end

Environment:
IntellJ, Wildfly21, Project on [GitHub](https://github.com/ViFire/docCore-backend)

When wildfly is started and I try to persist an entity, in the log I see always the
"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: entities.Account"

It is funny because if i execute a JUnit test the persistence worked perfectly.
I could "fix" the problem by adding classes in the persistence.xml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
                 version="2.2">
        <persistence-unit name="cleverCore">
            <description>Database connector</description>
            <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>entities.Account</class>
        <class>entities.AccountRole</class>            
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
            <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cleverCore" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="cleverCoreManager" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password123" />
    
                <!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files -->
                <property name="hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
                <!-- Enable the logging of all the generated SQL statements to the console -->
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <!-- validate, update, create, create-drop, non -->
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
                <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
                <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
    
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

I also added the autodection and hoped they will be auto detected but it is not the case. Is there any way that all @Entity classes will be detected on startup? I am pretty sure there must be a tiny setting i do not see yet.

```
package entities;

import helper.PasswordHelper;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "account_id", unique=true)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    @QueryParam("accountName")
    private String accountName;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @QueryParam("password")
    private String password;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "account_role")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<AccountRole> accountRoles = new HashSet<AccountRole>();

    public Account() {

    }

    public Account(String accountName, String password) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
        this.password = PasswordHelper.generatePassword(password);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }

    public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<AccountRole> getAccountRoles() {
        return accountRoles;
    }

    public void setAccountRoles(Set<AccountRole> accountRoles) {
        this.accountRoles = accountRoles;
    }

    public void addAccountRole(AccountRole role) {
        accountRoles.add(role);
    }

    public void removeAccountRole(AccountRole role) {
        accountRoles.remove(role);
    }

    public void encryptPassowrt(String unhashedPass) {
        this.password = PasswordHelper.generatePassword(unhashedPass);
    }

    public boolean isAuthorized(AccountRole role) {
        return accountRoles.contains(AccountRole.ADMIN)
                || accountRoles.contains(role);
    }

}
```

Comment: Additionally after checking the project I highly recommend you add a `.gitignore` file. Here are [some templates](https://github.com/github/gitignore). I suggest a mix of `Global/JetBrains.gitignore` and `Maven.gitignore`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Will add it.

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the same, I have a EJB jar and when wildfly startup faild with it did not map entities when try charge namedquery... could you solve  this case?

Comment: Hey, i could not solve it in this setup. I created a new project from scratch using jarkarta and wildfly 26. Also i use JTA instead of LOCAL_RESOURCE. In the persistence.xml i dit not mentioned any classes so they get detected automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The `persistence.xml` must be in the same jar/package/level as the classes being scanned, or if those classes are in a separate jar, you have to list it with the `jar-file` tags right before the `class` tags. If your `persistence.xml` resides separated from the classes in your final classpath, then you have to list every class with the `MappedSuperclass` `Embeddable` or `Entity` annotations.

You can check the classpaths scanned for the EntityManagerFactory, that doesn't change the solution.

I have a helper script that does just that, so I can load them in tests.

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -rEl '@(javax\.persistence\.)?(MappedSuperclass|Embeddable|Entity)' src/main/java/ | grep -oP '^[^\.]+' | LC_ALL=C sort | sed -e 's#/#.#g' | sed -re 's#^src.main.java.(.+)$#    <class>\1</class>#'
```

Comment: Everything in in the same WAR project. The persistence.xml is under the webapp- - WEB-INFfolder while the java classes in a separate package including Entitiy annotations. I thought that is the standard way to go.